# Spacy using all available CPU when running via Docker

Tags: numpy, spacy, spacy-transformers, data-scrubbing

I'm using [scrubadub_spacy](https://spacy.io/universe/project/scrubadub_spacy) to clean text documents. When processing a document in a Docker environment built on `amazonlinux`, it maxes out the 8 cores on my MacBook and in Amazon Fargate. I'm confused why this is happening. The problem sounds very similar to the one solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49711536/6781104), but it sounds like Spacy now uses [Blis](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1508#issuecomment-449169379), which is single-threaded, rather than BLAS. Also confusing is that if I install `scrubadub_spacy` in a virtual environment on my MacBook, I see about 3x better performance than when it is running in the container. Would anyone be able to help me understand what is going on here?

I was expecting the inference code to run on a single core and for performance to be similar when running in a container as when running outside of one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.